# splashscreen next activity not opening

Tags: android

I am very new to Android, I am developing an application. I want to run the splash screen, but somewhere wrong in my code, the splash screen is just opening and staying at the same page, but it is not opening the next activity, please anyone help me. My main aim is, "For a new user, it should first open the splash screen with `Setpassword.java` Activity (and the password should store in `sharedpreference`), but when a user sets password and closes the app and when he reopens, it should open the splashscreen with directly `enterpassword.java` Activity,i.e skipping `setpassword`. Java activity:

```
package com.example.shiva.secretbook;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.logging.Handler;

/**
* Created by shiva on 8/12/2017.
*/
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
String password;
ImageView imageViewSplash;
TextView txtAppName;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
Thread SplashThread;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
     // load password
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    password = settings.getString("password", "");
    imageViewSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplash);
    txtAppName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    startAnimations();
}

private void startAnimations(){
    Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate);
    Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
R.anim.translate);

    rotate.reset();
    translate.reset();
    relativeLayout.clearAnimation();

    imageViewSplash.startAnimation(rotate);
    txtAppName.startAnimation(translate);
    SplashThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            int waited = 0;
            while (waited < 3500) {
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                waited += 100;

            }
            if (password.equals("")){
                // if there is no password
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new 
  Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,setpassword.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                //if there is a password
                Intent intent = new 
    Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,enterpassword.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
    } SplashThread.start();
    }


};
}}
```

Comment: You got enough answers I think, But the main reason for the issue is, you are opening the activity in the different thread. You should run in Android Main thread, You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) topic.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setContentView(new SplashEnvironment(this, this));
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (password.equals("")){
            // if there is no password
            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            Intent intent = new 
          Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,setpassword.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {

            //if there is a password
            Intent intent = new 
Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,enterpassword.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
}
        // close this activity
    }
   }, 3000);// time for spalsh screen
```

Comment: bro, thank u for u r help, but i need the same splash screen to run, as our team loved that splash screen

Comment: pls guide me in my code, where should i change or update the code

Answer (score 1):

```
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   if (password.equals(""))
               {
                // if there is no password
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,setpassword.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
              } else
              {
                //if there is a password
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,enterpassword.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                }
                }
            }, 3500);
```

Comment: bro, i am very basic to android, so pls guide me where i should exactly place that code and also in Public void run function() i have some extra code, should i have to remove that? (once check my code bro...thanks)

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below Code**

```
public void StartAnimation(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (password.equals("")){
                    // if there is no password
                    SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
                    Intent intent = new
                            Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,setpassword.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    //if there is a password
                    Intent intent = new
                            Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,enterpassword.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    package com.wikitude.samples;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    /**
     * Created by shiva on 8/12/2017.
     */
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
        String password;
        ImageView imageViewSplash;
        TextView txtAppName;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
            // load password
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            password = settings.getString("password", "");
            imageViewSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplash);
            txtAppName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAppName);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
            startAnimations();
        }

        private void startAnimations() {
            Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
            Animation translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);

            rotate.reset();
            translate.reset();
            relativeLayout.clearAnimation();
            imageViewSplash.startAnimation(rotate);
            txtAppName.startAnimation(translate);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(launchNextScreen);
                }
            }, 3500);

        }

        public Runnable launchNextScreen = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (password.equals("")) {
                    // if there is no password
                    SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, setpassword.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    //if there is a password
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, enterpassword.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: bro, thanks a lot, but it showing error in runOnUiThread(launchNextScreen), (cannot find symbol launchNextScreen) and also illegal start of expression in  private Runnable launchNextScreen = new Runnable()

Comment: @ShivaLucky :  Make sure you have imported  'import android.os.Handler;' in your activity ,

Comment: yes bro, still it is showing "Cannot find symbol launchNextScreen"

Comment: now it is showing like Handler is abstract, cannot be instantiated, pls help me

Comment: @ShivaLucky : somehow am not getting 'Cannot find symbol launchNextScreen'  , anyhow  i have updated the code , Can you please check now ?

Comment: tq u very much for being patience with me sir..... splash screen has succesfully opened but the next activity is showing like "unfortunately it has stopped working", i just copied u r code and run it, it came the above sentence, "unfortunately it has stopped working" after the splash screen page    @Girish H, please help me sir, there is a small mistake somewhere in the code

Comment: some issue might be there next activity , need to check error log

Comment: there is no error sir in the next activity, .once check the above code sir about is everything write in it?, and in the setpassword.class i have two text fields showing set password and confirm passwords, thats it sir,  and in the enterpassword class i just have one field i.e , enter password only... thanks

Comment: the above error (unfortunately it stopped working) in emulator sir,

Answer (score 0):

You started your thread(SplashThread.start();) inside thread creation.

Due to this your thread unable to start.So just put this line on proper place I.e.

SplashThread = new Thread() {

};
SplashThread.start();

Comment: Welcome to SO, some proper answers have already been given. Kindly go through the reading section on how to ask and answer questions here on SO. cheers.

Comment: yes bro, tq, but after the splash screen it is showing that unfortunately it is stopped working

Comment: Please share me your crash log. or let me know which exception is occurring.